# "Only when..." vs "it was only when..."

Tags: phrases

In the following example:

> Eri stared at date on the screen, but all she saw were white pixels.
>   Only when she recovered from her shock that she became aware of its
>   meaning.

Do it have to add "*it was*" before "...only when..."? Or it's not necessary? When to use **only when** and when to use **it was only when**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to say either

> It was only when she recovered from her shock that she became aware of
>   its meaning.

or

> Only when she recovered from her shock did  she become aware of its
>   meaning.

Comment: small typo: `did she become` .  I can't edit because it's only one character =)

Answer (score 2):

As written, you have a sentence fragment. "Only when" introduces a prepositional phrase. "That" introduces a subordinate clause. You need to have a main clause, and there isn't one.

Adding "It was" makes it a sentence, so that's correct. A different way to do it would be to change "that" to "did" and "became" to "become".

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "only when" and "It was only when", both are very similarly used.

However there is a subtle difference in the pace/style of the story-telling in both cases.
In "**Only When**", there is a sense of urgency, a slightly more 'involved' writing.

"It was only when" is by comparision more 'relaxed' writing, more like someone is recounting something to someone.