# Only this way (we can)/(can we)? (Or why is negative inversion necessary?)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, differences

In general, we would say "Only this way can we", but I also came across many sentences in the internet which use “Only this way we can”.
Is the expression "Only this way we can" grammatically correct and natural?
Many thanks!

> "To find the best way of living a worthy life through a relatively uncharted experience, is simply by using our intuition. Only this way *we can* learn the wonders of eternal consciousness, and literately witness that it is alive and exists at all."(The Conspiracy Rhetoric of Mankind author: Paul J. Linke)

————

The above is the same question as in
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/only-this-way-we-can-can-we.3564026/ ; however, the answers there seem not to be theoretical or persuasive to explain why this grammar is necessary, so I copy and paste it here.

Comment: The quote seems very ungrammatical. The only Google books link for it shows that the rest of the book is a mess.       https://tinyurl.com/y5syby55

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inversion after Inversion after 'only when', 'only after', 'only if', 'only in this way' etc.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341696/inversion-after-only-when)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I just wonder why the grammar of negative inversion is necessary; I haven't found the answer in the link you post.

Comment: You've changed your question significantly now; I've checked the edits. I'd guess the origins of the inversion-after-'negative'-adverb requirement go back to former constructions and are now fossilised. It's interesting that 'infrequently' cannot be used with subject-auxiliary inversion although 'seldom' and 'rarely' can ... but then 'infrequently' is pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of **Negative Inversion**.

According to *Wikipedia*:

> In linguistics, *negative inversion* is one of many types of *subject–auxiliary* inversion in English. A negation (e.g. not, no, never, nothing, etc.) or a word that implies negation (**only**, hardly, scarcely) or a phrase containing one of these words precedes the finite auxiliary verb **necessitating that the subject and finite verb undergo inversion**. *Negative inversion* is a phenomenon of English syntax.

It's therefore correct to say:

*"Only this way can we learn the wonders of eternal consciousness, and literately witness that it is alive and exists at all."*

Comment: Hmm. Nice post, but doesn’t answer the OP’s question!

Comment: @Araucaria- Not here any more Welcome! Where do you find my answer deficient? One could flesh it out by adding more examples perhaps, but the basic question about which version of OP's sentence is correct is IMHO dealt with sufficiently.

Comment: Well, it’s just that OP seems completely aware that the version with subject auxiliary inversion is grammatical. What they want to know is whether the version *without* it is. This isn’t covered by the Wiki quote and you don’t specifically rule it out in your answer!

Comment: I thought bolding **necessitating that the subject and finite verb undergo inversion** was enough for OP to know the other version is ungrammatical. But i defer to your superior knowledge of such things (indeed, linguistics in general), and so I would like you to add what's been left out. Or better still, write a detailed answer. :)

Comment: Well, compare, *For no reason, Trump would dance naked* and  *For no reason would Trump dance naked*. :-) Or *Only after considering the consequences, people should undertake potentially lethal actions* and *Only after considering the consequences should people undertake potentially lethal actions*. The Wiki description isn’t complete/accurate!

Comment: @user405662 Thanks for your being the first to respond to my question, and indeed your answer helps. But "necessitating that the subject and finite verb undergo inversion" just seems not to be adequate for my need.

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more. Thanks for your making my question more specific.

Comment: @Araucaria- Not here any more I can see that my answer is indeed incomplete without addressing the part brought out by your examples. The _comma_ version in your examples doesn't call for _S-V inversion_ because the phrases preceding commas aren't part of the matrix clause,while this is not so in the _commaless_ version. To put it in a crude way. Right?

Comment: Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+this+way+can%2Conly+in+this+way+can&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20this%20way%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20in%20this%20way%20can%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Conly%20this%20way%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20in%20this%20way%20can%3B%2Cc00) shows that *Only **in** this way can we ...* is much more frequent than *Only this way can ...*

Comment: @user405662 It's about whether the whole sentence is negated or not.  (If it is, there's SAI)